# haskell - cabal install hint : error Module `ErrUtils' does not export `pprErrMsgBagWithLoc'

Tags: haskell, cabal, hint

While trying to install `hint` on my machine *Debian GNU/Linux 7.6 (wheezy)* with `ghc 7.4.1` and `cabal-install version 0.14.0`
 `using version 1.14.0 of the Cabal library`

I got the following error:

```
Registering ghc-paths-0.1.0.9...
Downloading hint-0.4.2.2...
Configuring hint-0.4.2.2...
Building hint-0.4.2.2...
Preprocessing library hint-0.4.2.2...
[ 1 of 23] Compiling Hint.SignalHandlers ( src/Hint/SignalHandlers.hs, dist/build/Hint/SignalHandlers.o )
[ 2 of 23] Compiling Hint.Util        ( src/Hint/Util.hs, dist/build/Hint/Util.o )
[ 3 of 23] Compiling Hint.CompatPlatform ( src/Hint/CompatPlatform.hs, dist/build/Hint/CompatPlatform.o )
[ 4 of 23] Compiling Hint.GHC         ( src/Hint/GHC.hs, dist/build/Hint/GHC.o )

src/Hint/GHC.hs:45:37:
    Module `ErrUtils' does not export `pprErrMsgBagWithLoc'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
hint-0.4.2.2 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: I would guess that the one of the packages does not have it's `build-depends` configured correctly...

Comment: More specifically, it looks like the package version bounds are wrong.

Comment: If I had to guess, it would be the older version of `ghc`. We are on version `7.10.2` currently and the OP is compiling with `7.4.1`. The version of `base` he is using might not be compatible with the package. Still the package configuration should define that in the `build-depends` section...